# I would like to implement python code with inverse kinematics

Tags: ros, kinematics, python, ros-kinetic, inverse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using a CrustCrawler Smart arm, and I would like to feed new coordinates to it via inverse Kinematics in Python, since it is used in our environment. Trac_ik has been used before here, but I can't find anyone to speak about this on how this works, is there anyone who can?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295936/i-would-like-to-implement-python-code-with-inverse-kinematics/) by [NLBUURMAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/36191/nlbuurman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `trak_ik` repository has [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik/src/HEAD/trac_ik_python/) about how the Python API works. It also states that the Python API is just a SWIG wrapper around the C API so you could look at the documentation for that, too (although there doesn't seem to be much). Finally, `trac_ik` claims to be a drop-in replacement for the KDL solver, so look at the [KDL API documentation](http://www.orocos.org/kdl) to see how that works. The [wiki page for `trac_ik`](http://wiki.ros.org/trac_ik) says that these are the only differences:

> TRAC-IK has a very similar API to
> KDL's IK solver calls, except that the
> user passes a maximum time instead of
> a maximum number of search iterations.
> Additionally, TRAC-IK allows for error
> tolerances to be set independently for
> each Cartesian dimension (x, y, z,
> roll, pitch & yaw).

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2018-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NLBUURMAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/36191/nlbuurman/) on 2018-07-10**:
thanks! I'll have a look at that :)